# Is a bad approach to set boost SQL Server (Express 2008) priority on VPS with only SqlServer + IIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis-7, vps

I'm looking for increase performance on SQL-Server reads/writes, I'm tunning all my queries, but I'm thinking on if it's a good idea to set on the boost SQL Server priority on.

The system is a VPS with:

- 2 Virtual Processors with 2 Cores each one, 2,5 GB RAM
- Windows Server 2008
- SQL-Server 2008 Express
- IIS 7

How much could affect to IIS doing this? I read about SQL Express version uses only one processor, so I have 2 cores free to Windows+IIS work, Isn't it?

It is possible also to loose connection through remote desktop?

thanks!

Comment: It's never been recommended (even assuming that a higher priority would affect I/O performance); http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2010/01/27/priority-boost-details-and-why-it-s-not-recommended.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Priority does not mean "faster". It means "first this, then everything else". Total throughput does not change. If it did Windows would just run everything at high priority all the time.

Almost never should you turn on this option. Don't turn it on. It won't help and it might destabilize the system.